# Using Visual Studio 2015 phone emmulator on windows 10,

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-10, visual-studio-2015

I am using windows 10 and Visual Studio Community 2015.. My question is The app I am making cannot be debugged, its says that My Windows 10 does not support the emulator, so I need to register my phone to debug the app.

However, I am developing on windows 10 and creating a windows 8.1 phone app. I have changed the laptop into Developer Mode, and I still cannot figure out how to register the phone.

My laptop specs are:

Windows 10 Home
500 GB
4 GB RAM
Intel Pentium N3540 Processor
64 bit OS

My Phone specs are:

Windows 8.1 Pro update 2
Lumia 640 LTE

So if the emulator is not supported in windows 10, then how do I register my phone. There has to be away to debug the app.

Update:

```
Hyper-V Requirements:     
                           VM Monitor Mode Extensions: Yes
                           Virtualization Enabled In Firmware: No
                           Second Level Address Translation: Yes
                           Data Execution Prevention Available: Yes
```

Comment: The emulator uses Hyper-V. Verify your system has Hardware Virtualization enabled in your BIOS/EFI settings then install Hyper-V through the Control Panel.

Comment: that would be done through the bios correct

Comment: Hyper-V Requirements:  VM Monitor Mode Extensions: Yes
                           Virtualization Enabled In Firmware: No
                           Second Level Address Translation: Yes
                           Data Execution Prevention Available: Yes

Comment: You need SLAT enabled for Hyper-V.

Comment: I know I need SLAT enabled but programs and features does not have Hyper-v in the list.. So how would I enable it, I tried to enable everything through DSIM on elevated cmd.. But its not found

Comment: Ah, I forgot. Windows 10 Home does not include Hyper-V.

Comment: Yes windows 10 has all the hyper-v preaquites.. I downloaded the emmulator, but it still says I need a perquisite of windows 8.1 pro. So now how would I use my phone to debug

Comment: You need to upgrade to Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: ah ok, I wish visual studio would tell you all this.. I am used to developing in Win8.1 Pro

Answer (score 0):

In order for the hyper-v to work on win10, you must enable it through the BIOS.. Once its enabled then you can install the emulator...